# How can my discord bot send a welcome message and give a role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want that my discord bot sends a message on a specific channel and give a specific role everytime a new user joins the server

But my bot is doing nothing and I'm getting no errors

```
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive



class MyClient(discord.Client):


    #Beim Einloggen
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("BOT is online")

    async def on_member_join(member):
      role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id=<role_id>)
      channel = MyClient.get_channel(<channel_id>)
      await MyClient.add_roles(member, role)
      await channel.send(f"Hello {member} nice to see you!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for the user greeting (in a cog):

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    channel = member.guild.system_channel
    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(f"Welcome to the server {member.mention}!")
```

Basically, you are missing theese `@commands.Cog.listener()`'s

Comment: The OP isn't using a Cog, they subclassed the Bot class, so using `Cog.listener()`  isn't necessary.

Comment: I tried it like that, but nothing is Happening. I also added Cog

Answer (score 0):

Try this! (This isn't used in a cog)

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):

  if member.guild.id !=<YOUR_GUILD_ID>:    
    return 
  welcomerole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="<ROLE_NAME>")
  await member.add_roles(welcomerole)
  channel = client.get_channel(<WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID)
  await channel.send("<WHAT_YOU_WANT>")
```

*This makes it so when someone joins YOUR server it will send a custom message of your choice to the welcome channel*

> MAKE SURE YOU ADD YOUR GUILD ID IN <YOUR_GUILD_ID>

> MAKE SURE YOU ADD A CUSTOM MESSAGE WHEN A MEMBER JOINS IN <WHAT_YOU_WANT>

> MAKE SURE YOU ADD YOUR WELCOME CHANNEL ID IN <WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID>

> MAKE SURE YOU ADD THE ROLE NAME THAT YOU GET WHEN A MEMBER JOINS IN <ROLE_NAME>